# how to handle gridview rowcommand for nested gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I've got a nested gridview and am having issues with handling the rowcommand event. the language is vb.net.

panel
 gridview1
  template field
   gridview2
    template field
     image button

so in the above illustration, the image button is supposed to perform a delete of the given data row. this works; however, i keep receiving an error on the 2nd gridview:

JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The GridView 'gvSItems' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled.

this is triggered in the 2nd gridview rowcommand where i get the id for the row and pass it to a method to perform the row delete.

i tried adding the:  handles gridview2.rowcommand but the gridview isn't located since it is nested.

any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can either add the `OnRowCommand` handler to the markup of your GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvNested" runat="server"
    OnRowCommand="gvNested_RowCommand">
</asp:GridView>
```

Or add the handler to the nested GridView in the parent GridView's `OnRowDataBound` handler:

```
Protected Sub gvParent_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvParent.RowDataBound

    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then

        Dim gvNested As GridView = e.Row.FindControl("gvNested")
        AddHandler gvNested.RowCommand, AddressOf gvNested_RowCommand

    End If

End Sub
```